# How to WordPress custom post done as single.php post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created WordPress Custom post in a top section for showing a Prime Post With a big Image. I want to show this post as single.php post as well as by a read more option.

But read more option not showing the post like single post. Result giving 404 not found. Code is below.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">

                <?php 
                $primepost = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type'=> 'Prime-posts',
                'posts_per_page'=> 1
                ));
                ?>

            <div class="prime-post-title fix">
            <?php while($primepost->have_posts()):$primepost->the_post();?>

                        <div class="prime-postimage fix">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>" alt="" />
                        </div>  
                        <div class="banner-inf">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                                <?php read_more(40);?>  <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More</a>
                        </div>  
            <?php endwhile;?>                           
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi Akram. The first version of your post contained txtspk (i.e. the abbreviated nonsense of "plz"), a misspelling, chat not germaine to the question and missed out some of your HTML (due to a malformed Markdown block). I will be rolling it back. If you really want the earlier version, let me know and I will flag it for a moderator. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add unique `slug` . Then create `post_type-single.php` template. 
Or use custom post type template plugin.